# How can I improve performance of my application which generates XML using Linq-to-Entities and XElement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

I have built an application that generates a large XML file using Linq-to-Entities and XElement. It takes a whole core of our 2GHz server for about half an hour and uses ~1GB of memory.

I'm doing the following type of work:

```
var xml = from x in dbContext.Table1
          select new XElement("Table1",
                     new XElement("Field1", x.Field1),
                     new XElement("Field2", x.Field2),
                     new XElement("Field3", x.Field3),
                     new XElement("MoreFields",
                         new XElement("FieldA", x.MoreFields.FieldA),
                         new XElement("FieldA", x.MoreFields.FieldA),
                         new XElement("FieldA", x.MoreFields.FieldA.DoSomeWorkWithThisField())
    )
);
```

I have another level of depth or two and several of the fields have work done like parsing an `int` out of a string using `RegEx.Match()`

Does anyone have any optimization or refactoring recommendations? I tried using `XStreamingElement` but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I think the issue here is more likely to do with how you are using the dbcontext. Is this working code? Is Table1 an `IQueryable<OfSomething>`. It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: You're right I'll fix it. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're fetching the whole of `Table1` multiple times.

Can you fetch it to a `List<T>` and then use that repeatedly?

```
var list = dbContext.Table1.ToList();
var xml = new XElement("Table1",
    new XElement("Field1", list.Field1),
    new XElement("Field2", list.Field2),
    new XElement("Field3", list.Field3),
    new XElement("MoreFields",
        new XElement("FieldA", list.MoreFields.FieldA),
        new XElement("FieldA", list.MoreFields.FieldA),
        new XElement("FieldA", list.MoreFields.FieldA.DoSomeWorkWithThisField())
    )
);
```

I suspect there's rather more involved than this, but basically - fetch what you need into memory up-front, and then work from that. If you only need to use an item of data once, that's fine to do only when you need it - but avoid pulling the same data time and time again.

How big is the document you're generating, and how much memory does your machine have? You might want to try looking at the performance counters - it's possible that you're spending most of the time garbage collecting.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this tomorrow. I was under the impression that Linq-to-Entities would understand that I am referencing the same table multiple times when it builds the SQL statements. Do you know of any good reading material for using Linq-to-Entities to generate `XElements`?

Answer (score 0):

For large documents you should consider a streaming solution like `XmlWriter` instead of a solution like `XDocument` which keeps all the data in memory.